# How to find the average of character of multiple string in C

Tags: c

I do have very few idea on string. Will you please tell me how to find the average of character in multiple string?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int count_char=0,i;
int sum,average;
char str1[80];
char str2[80];
char str3[80];

printf("Enter string 1 : ");
gets(str1);
printf("Enter string 2 : ");
gets(str2);
printf("Enter string 3 : ");
gets(str3);
for(i=0; str1[i]!=0; i++)
{
count_char++;
if(str1[i]==0)
i++;
}

printf("\nNumber of characters in string 1 : %d",count_char,str1);
getch();
count_char=0;
for(i=0; str2[i]!=0; i++)
{
count_char++;
if(str2[i]==0)
i++;
}
printf("\nNumber of characters in string 2 : %d",count_char,str2);
getch();
count_char=0;
for(i=0; str3[i]!=0; i++)
{
count_char++;
if(str2[i]==0)
i++;
}
printf("\nNumber of characters in string 3 : %d",count_char,str3);
getch();


return 0;
}
```

*I want to fidn the average of the multiple string of my code. But i could not. will you please help me. I don't understand how to do it

Comment: Didn't you just post this exact same question? Don't do that! If you have updates to a question then *edit* the question, don't delete it and repost. In fact, don't delete and repost the same question no matter the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Take the sum of the count of characters and divide by the number of strings.

As a point of interest, this is how you always calculate the average, of anything. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to get the number of characters in a string.

```
int len1 = strlen(str1);
```

then, just calculate the average:

```
float avg = (len1 + len2 + len3) / 3;
```